# Searchbox for a table

Tags: tables, longtable, pgfplotstable

I'm new to LaTeX. 
I was wondering if it is possible to create a searchbox for a table (in LaTeX) which would then work in the pdf. I don't want to just display the word as in the find function. I'd like the actual table to change depending on the row name, or date entered.

I guess that it's not possible as there aren't any other questions like this, or maybe I haven't searched enough.

Edit: I have a list of clients, each with their own numeric KPIs. 
And I want account managers to be able to view how their clients have performed.
I could make a new chapter per client and have it all in there. 
But I want a quick summary of who has performed well depending on what kpi we are talking about.

So 
text.
Table, where after you type in your client the table becomes two or three rows.
then text again.

rather than

text .
huge table.
scroll scroll scroll.
text.

Then if possible have a plot is also dependent on the search.

Comment: You want dynamic content? That is pretty hard in general. Your particular question (as I interpret it) seems almost impossible to me. But, if you can clarify if/how the content should be dynamic, maybe more can be said.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please clarify what do you exactly want to achieve. Do you want to check if a row/column/cell of a table contains some string, and add information depending on what is found? Which "row name" or "date" are you talking about. They did not appear in your post. And as a side remark: The non-existance of a question does not automatically mean that it is not possible to solve it or not worth to ask.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think LaTeX is the way to go here. This sounds more like something you would do with a database and some query language + HTML to format the results.